# How Adaboost and decision tree features importances differ?

Tags: classification, decision-tree, feature-selection, adaboost

I have a multiclass classification problem and I extracted features importances based on impurity decrease. I compared a decision tree and AdaBoost classifiers and I ovserved that there is a feature that was ranked on top with the decision tree while it has a very lower importance according to AdaBoost.
Is that a normal behavior?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal behavior. The features importance calculates a score for all the input features of a model. However, each model has a (slightly) different technique. For example: a linear regression will look at linear relationships. If a feature has a perfect linear relationship with your target, then it will have a high feature importance. Features with a non-linear relationship may not improve the accuracy resulting in a lower feature importance score.

There is some research related to the difference in feature importance measures. An example is:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42452-021-04148-9